# Transaction API not working in mobile google assistance

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Google Transaction API has been implemented in Dialogflow Fulfillment. In my intent function my code is like `agent.add(agent.conv().ask(new TransactionRequirements()))`. This code was running properly and giving response in google action console only before deployment in alpha test. But that time in mobile google assistance there were no response as well as no log in google firebase function. After deployment in alpha test the response is coming in google action console i.e

> DISPLAY REQUEST RESPONSE AUDIO DEBUG ERRORS Invocation Error You
>   cannot use standard Google Assistant features in the Simulator. If you
>   want to try them, use Google Assistant on your phone or other
>   compatible devices.

Now also in mobile google assistant still response not coming. What is the solution for that?

Comment: hi, are you able to solve this? even i am getting the same issue

Comment: Yes I have resolved the problem @stackjohnny

Comment: how? can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

```html
let tran = new TransactionRequirements();

agent.setContext(context);
agent.add(agent.conv()
  .ask(tran)
)
```

@stackjohnny